# user: dbo unable to drop database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, drop-database

I have a SQL agent job whereby we do a restore of a full backup of production data on a nightly basis. We are setting up a new server and when I attempt to run the job on the new server I receive an error on the job of

> 3701 - Cannot drop database because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

This is confounding me because we are using the `dbo` user to accomplish this step and the database is listed in `sys.databases` catalog view. I have tried altering the database to put it into single_user to no avail.

The first step of the job kills all connections and that passes. I am not sure where this error is coming from because everything looks in accord to me. We can also drop the database manually through logging in as the `sa`.

Comment: Is your context the `master` database? You might be defaulting to the database you are trying to drop and I think you need to be in `master` to be able to drop the database..

Comment: In the job, the particular step, uses the master database (i.e. @database_name = master)

Comment: Could you do a `select suser_name()` and see what you get?

Comment: on the sql job.. did you select run as "sa" and specified the database? for the script to run?

Comment: I have figured out a way to get this to work.  I am not sure why the dbo was unable to run but I accomplished the step through sqlcmd.

Comment: Is that case sensitive server?